# if Metadata API supports retrieving Enhanced Letterhead?

Tags: api, metadata

I have a question about Metadata API.

Is there any ability to retrieve Enhanced Letterhead via Metadata API?
I checked specs, so I found that Metadata API supports only Classic Letterheads. So it that true?

Comment: Based on [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/56), Enhanced Letterhead is not available yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Letterhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_letterhead.htm) is Metadata

[EnhancedLetterhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_enhancedletterhead.htm) is an object, and data.

My assumption would be that you need to migrate the data of the `EnhancedLetterhead` records and cannot use the Metadata API.