# Retrieve Enhanced Letterhead via Metadata API

Tags: metadata, visualstudiocode, letterhead

Can someone please point me to a blog or walk me through steps for retrieving Lightning Enhanced Letterheads in VSC.

I can see the classic letter head in VSC but not lightning Enhanced Letterhead, and I see the reason why [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385799/if-metadata-api-supports-retrieving-enhanced-letterhead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnhancedLetterHead is not available in the Metadata Coverage Report :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/57